# Inline editing tab order

Tags: bug, status-declined, edits, design, keyboard-shortcuts

The tab order of line editing groups similar elements by type (e.g. post body, submit button) instead of post. Probably because this is how `tabindex` works in HTML when you ignore the possibility of having multiple posts' editors visible simultaneously and assign the same index to all elements of the same type.

This is *insane*.

I sometimes abort editing one post *but leave the editor open* (and ignore it, I mean, why not? I can!). Then, when editing a different post, and tabbing e.g. from the description field to the submit button, *some UI element of the other post's editor is focused!*

**Steps to reproduce**

1. You need 2k reputation or so, or have a symbol next to your user name.
2. Go to a question with at least one answer.
3. Click *edit* on the question.
4. Decide the question is fine after all.
5. Click *edit* on the answer.
6. Pretend you changed something here and press `Tab`.
7. Be confused by the tab order, which caused the browser to focus the question's tag list.

---

I assume this is a bug, because I just cannot imagine that someone thought this makes any sense.

Please fix the tab order by taking into account multiple open editors (i.e. don't start at `1` — or `81` — on every post), or just close one editor when opening another one.

Comment: All post bodies are `tabindex` 81, all editing summaries are 89, etc., so it's like I guessed.

Comment: I see two easy solutions for this. Set the `tabindex` values to match the following structure: **Section 1** `{1, 2, 3}`, **Section 2** `{4, 5, 6}`, ... OR **Section 1** `{1, 1, 1}` **Section 2** `{2, 2, 2}`. The browser should then move the focus intuitively, from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a fairly rare scenario. If you decide something doesn't need editing, hit `cancel`.

Comment: I face it quite often actually. Typically when I want to copy parte of the question source to the answer.

Comment: Why not hit cancel for me when I'm opening multiple editors? If it's as rare as you claim, nobody will complain about this change.